# Notation for iterative application of a function with two arguments

Tags: functions, notation

I have a function $f: X \times 2^C \rightarrow 2^C$. I was wondering how I would be able to show this function being applied iteratively over a sequence of elements $X_s$. For example, assuming I had $X_s = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dotsc, x_n)$ and a $C' \subseteq C$ I was wondering if there was a convenient notation to represent $f(x_n, f(x_{n - 1}, \dotsc, f(x_3, f(x_2, f(x_1, C')))\dotso))$?

Comment: I don't think there's standard notation for that - I would introduce your own, explicitly, and be clear and consistent. For instance, maybe $f(C'; x_1, . . . , x_n)$?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - I will go ahead and define some explicit notation and then use that; your example looks quite sensible. Thanks!